# Metadata/Tooling API - Identify orphaned email alerts (workflow actions no longer associated to an workflow)

Tags: workflow, metadata-api, appexchange, metadata, tooling-api

I was looking to cleanup some of our orgs metadata and identify the email alerts that do not have an active workflow.

Is there a way, besides parsing the metadata and finding metadata tag matches on the *.workflow xml files to quickly determine this?

Perhaps an app-exchange package?

```
<alerts> 
        <fullName>HERE_IS_AN_ACTION <!--email alert dev name-->

    <rules>
        <fullName>BI ED Opp Closed</fullName>
        <actions>
            <name>HERE_IS_AN_ACTION</name> <!--email alert is in Workflow-->
            <type>Alert</type>
```

Comment: You could try [WorkflowAlert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowalert.htm) from the Tooling API.